# react-easy-marquee Warning in console

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hadoop-yarn

Warning: Updating a style property during rerender (animation) when a conflicting property is set (animationPlayState) can lead to styling bugs. To avoid this, don't mix shorthand and non-shorthand properties for the same value; instead, replace the shorthand with separate values.